# Как компилировать исходники c#?

Tags: c#

Вообщем прислали тестовое задание. Задание решил, но тут в требованиях к оформлению увидел следующее [image: требования к решениям]
Задание делал в Visual Studio. Как изменить исходники под эту команду? Вообщем как этой командой запустить, скажем, "hello wordl" на c#?

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/

Comment: Это и есть ответ. Зачем в комментариях пишите

Comment: Выше - просо ссылка, отправлять в ответ ссылку не очень хорошо... А расписывать все подробно я что то не очень хочу, ибо с моно вообще не знаком. Если у вас есть желание и вы разобрались, то можете сами оформить ответ, от меня лайк получите ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ссылка https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/ ведет на скачивание дистрибутива MONO.

Там же можно найти ссылку с гайдом на установку. Вот для винды https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/windows/

После установки

1. Открываем консольное приложение "Open Mono Command Prompt".
2. Переходим в корень проекта `cd C:\koren_proecta\`
3. И командой из вопроса у меня всё компилится.